# Xquery - return only distinct attributes from if/then

Tags: xpath, xquery

I've been trying to write a query to get distinct attribute values after using if/then to determine whether I'll use the element in the first place. Here's my example xml and the query i've written so far:

```
<donors>
    <donor donor_id="x21" cn_id="x12">
        <homeless>$1201</homeless>
        <conservation>$300</conservation>
        <cancerResearch>$250</cancerResearch>
    </donor>
    <donor donor_id="x23" cn_id="x13">
        <homeless>$121</homeless>
        <conservation>$30</conservation>
        <cancerResearch>$50</cancerResearch>
    </donor>
    <donor donor_id="x24" cn_id="x14">
        <homeless>$1201</homeless>
        <cancerResearch>$250</cancerResearch>
    </donor>
    <donor donor_id="x25" cn_id="x12">
        <homeless>$1201</homeless>
        <conservation>$300</conservation>
        <cancerResearch>$250</cancerResearch>
    </donor>
</donors>
```

I want to first get all donors who have a child "conservation". I've done the following for that:

```
<conservationists>
{
for $x in //donor
return
    if(exists($x/conservation))
    then <conservationist cn_id="{$x/@cn_id}/>
    else ()
}
</conservationists>
```

I tried wrapping the whole thing in distinct-values but that just gave nothing, and every where else I tried doing something to that effect I just ended up with an end tag.

Answer (score 3):

This is one possible way :

```
<conservationists>
{
    for $x in distinct-values(//donor[conservation]/@cn_id)
    return
        <conservationist cn_id="{$x}"/>
}
</conservationists>
```

**<kbd>[`xpathtester demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xquery/f5fc05f1eb1a8f42047d7f87853e78c7)</kbd>**

The expression `distinct-values(//donor[conservation]/@cn_id)` returns distinct values of `cn_id` attribute from `donor` elements that have at least one `conservation` child element.

Comment: This does work. 
Could I ask you a quick follow up? 
If I wanted to try an alternative: those who do not have conservation, how would I just add [not(exists(conservation))]

Comment: Yes, you can modify the predicate like that. `donor[not(conservation)]` also works for me...